# What's the difference between varchar(255) and varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance

I was asked an interesting question today. I've thought about it before but couldn't come up with a good answer.

If the values of a column are only going to be <= 255 characters, is there any real difference between using varchar(255) and varchar(max).

I realize that `varchar(255)` has a limit of 255 characters and `varchar(max)` 2 gb but they only use as much space as needed for the actual values stored. I'm not counting the extra space needed for the `var` part because as far as I know it's the same (or is it?). So in terms of performance & space is there a difference?